# How to handle query parameters with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Follow the document in : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters

How i handle this parameters in Controller  file :

```
url: "/contacts?myParam"
```

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: How i get parameters values in controller ? ( like: ":contacts " , "myParam1")

Comment: `$stateParams.myParam1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$stateProvider` it's done like this, in the config section of your `app.js` declare the url as follows, here I use 3 parameters

```
.state('menu.section',{
            url:'/my_section/:param1/:param2/:param3',
```

Then include `$stateParamas` in your controller and you can use the parameters

```
myapp.controller('myController',["$scope", "stateParamas", function ($scope, stateParamas ) {
param1 = $stateParams.param1
param2 = $stateParams.param2
param3 = $stateParams.param3
...
```